# Right way to use for loop inside the test-bench to cover all possible cases

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, test-bench

I'm creating a test-bench for a top-level entity. It uses several components including 2x 8:1 mux at the end producing 2 separate outputs. I decided to use "for loop" to cover all cases but my input data gets assigned to my output data at random instances (instead it needs to be; input=output whenever Rd=Rs and/or Rd=Rt).

```
---
stim_proc  :PROCESS
begin
---

for Rd_loop in 0 to 7 loop -- 0 to 7 for Rd'lenght-1=2
    for Rs-Rt_loop in 0 to 7 loop -- 0 to 7 for Rs'lenght-1=Rt'lenght-1=2
        wait for 10 ns;

-- increment to the next value of Rs and Rt.

        Rs<=std_logic_vector( signed(Rs) + 1 );
        Rt<=std_logic_vector( signed(Rt) + 1 );
    end loop;

-- increment to the next value of Rd.
Rd<=std_logic_vector( signed(Rd) + 1 );
end loop;

        wait for 10 ns;

-----
```

I'm almost certain I should use a variable but couldn't figure out how to, appreciate any help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? your code will update the signals just fine.

Comment: Rs-Rt_loop is not a valid identifier for use in a loop parameter specification. If you're partial to having the minus sign in the name make it an extended identifier `\Rs-Rt_loop\\` (which would be even more painful to type). See IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.4 Identifiers. The wait statement in the inner loop allows assigning signals in the loop just find.

Answer (score 0):

This code turned out to be working just fine sorry for the confusion. I was just confused by the simulation output, thought I'm not getting the response I wanted but looking at the internal signals it's obvious that is the way it should behave.

So I decided not to use loops in a complex system's test bench next time unless I absolutely have to.

Thanks to both commenters as you're both right, signals are updated as they should with loop working just fine and there shouldn't be an "-" in between Rs and Rt.